Existence and uniqueness for ODE when $f(x, t)$ is not continuous
The Picard-Lindelöf theorem guarantees that the initial value problem
$$ \dot{x} = f(x, t), \;\;\; x(0) = x_0 $$
has a unique solution, at least on some interval, if $f(x, t)$ is continuous in $t$ and Lipshitz continuous in $x$. However, it seems to me that there are examples where there are unique solutions even if $f(x, t)$ is not continuous in $x$. For example,
$$f(x, t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} 1 & \mathrm{if}  & x < 0, \\ 2 & \mathrm{otherwise}.\end{array} \right. $$
For any initial value $x_0$, the solution (in a $t$-$x$ plot) would just be a straight line with slope 1 for $x<0$, and a straight line with slope 2 for $x\geq 0$, as shown in the figure below. None of those lines are going to intersect, unless they are the same line, so solutions both exist and are unique.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this just a case where solutions exist and are unique, even if this was not guaranteed by Picard-Lindelöf to be the case? And if so, are there other theorems that can shed some light on this case?
Edit:
Just to provide a bit more background, my motivation is that I read about a similar case as what I've outlined above, where
$$f(x, t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} 0 & \mathrm{if}  & x = 0, \\ 1 & \mathrm{otherwise},\end{array} \right. $$
and
$$ x(0) = 0, $$
in which case I guess solutions are not unique: For any $t' > 0$,
$$x(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} (t - t') & \mathrm{if}  & t > t' \\ 0 & \mathrm{otherwise},\end{array} \right. $$
is a solution, thus there are infinitely many solutions for the same initial value.

In this answer I am going to point some necessary conditions when the initial value problem
$$ \dot{x} = f(x, t), \;\;\; x(0) = x_0\tag{1}$$
has a solution on some interval.
As far as I see, if $x_0<0$ then the functions whose graphs are drawn at the figure fail to be differentiable at $t=-x_0$, so they fail to be solutions of the equation $(1)$ at this $t$. The similar remark concerns the example after the edit, where the function $x(t)$ fails to be differentiable at $t'$.
In general, not every integrable function is a derivative. Indeed, by Lebesgue theorem, a bounded function $f$ on a segment is Riemann integrable iff the set of the discontinuity points of $f$ has the Lebesgue measure $0$. On the other hand, by Darboux's theorem, the derivative has the intermediate value property: the image of an interval is also an interval. Namely, let $a<b$ be any real numbers
and $x:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be any differentiable function. Then for each $c$ between $x'(a)$ and $x'(b)$ there exists $t\in [a,b]$ such that $x'(t)=c$.
I am looking for more details about the restriction on discontinues of derivatives.

Interesting, I had just assumed that the lines shown in the figure were acceptable solutions. Can't I argue that they are a solution in all points, since I defined the "slope" of the lines to be 1 on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$, and then 2 on the interval $[0, \infty)$? So in each point, there is a well-defined derivative?

@Tor Right, your arguments are plausible, but, unfortunately, the proposed function $x(t)$ violates Darboux's theorem. The problem can be illustrated by the following example. Suppose that $x(t)$ equals $t$, if $t\le 0$ and equals $2t$, if $t\ge 0$. Then $\dot{x}(t)$ equals $1$, if $t<0$ and equals $2$, if $t>0$. But at $0$ the derivative of $x(t)$ from the left equals $1$, whereas the derivative of $x(t)$ from the right equals $2$.

I see that people use ODEs with discontinuous right-hand side in practice, though. See for example pages 196-198 in Hairer, Nørsett & Wanner: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1
And also the examples I gave in the figure seem to work in practice. Are there some less stringent conditions for something to be a solution to an ODE? I seem to recall there is something called a "weak solution" or "solution in the weak sense" or something like that?
